# Hide an element conditionally by its value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a kendo grid containing following columns.

1.Name

2.Age

3.Type{values:public,private}

I need to hide a column in specific row. In my problem, i want to hide age cell if Type value is private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using if else format

```
 columns.Template(@<text></text>)
                        .ClientTemplate("#if (field == value) {#"
                        + "<a></a>"
                        + "#}else {#"
                        +"<input name='chkSubscribed' class='subscribedClass'type='type': '' #/>"
                        + "#} #").Width(130).Title("title");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide the cell but you can hide the age depending of the other columns. See https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-apply-conditional-logic-to-client-column-templates on how to apply conditional logic to columns?

Comment: i would like to hide the value of the particular cell not the whole cell

Comment: Well, that is exactly what my post is about. Did you check the linked example? Did you give it a try?

Comment: Okay, now you've lost me. Which checkbox? Where is the code you've tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt.

Comment: i just need to empty the cell conditionally

Comment: I can only repeat myself: Did you check the linked example? There is an example on how to set the content conditionally. Did you give it a try?

Comment: Instead of "No data" message, i would like to remain as an empty column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192721/discussion-between-johnmathew-and-carsten-franke).