# Hide a check box conditionally

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid containing following columns.

1.Name

2.Age

3.Gender{checkbox(male, female)}

I need to hide a column in specific row. In my problem, want to hide Gender cell which contain checkbox if Age value equal to 18 or 19 or 20.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide an element conditionally by its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949597/hide-an-element-conditionally-by-its-value)

Answer (score 1):

As @Carsten said, you can't hide a cell, but only hide it's content. You can use a `template` for that:

```
template: "# if (data.Age < 18 || data.Age > 20) { #<input type='checkbox' name='Gender'># } #"
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ayEdAKan)

In your case, using Asp.Net MVC you should use `ClientTemplate`. Something like this(can't test it):

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Gender).ClientTemplate("# if (data.Age < 18 || data.Age > 20) { #<input type='checkbox' name='Gender'># } #")
```

[Source 1](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-apply-conditional-logic-to-client-column-templates), [source 2](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/client-detail-template), [source 3](https://www.telerik.com/forums/clienttemplate-using)

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the cell but you can hide the content depending of the other columns. See https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-apply-conditional-logic-to-client-column-templates on how to apply conditional logic to columns.